# PHP regex to select text after square brackets containing any text

Tags: php, regex

I need to match and work with the following text

```
... and the start date is [startDate]|(D jS M Y g:iA).
```

The match should return any characters between the `()` brackets after `[startDate]|` (in this case `D jS M Y g:iA`), but should be dynamic so that it matches anything after the `[ ]|`. Ie should also work with the tag `[otherDate]|(D jS M Y)`

I've tried using positive look aheads, but haven't been able to get the result I need.

Comment: \[[^\[\]]+\]\|\((.*?)(?=\))

Comment: How does your current code look like?

Comment: Is this a template language? It looks like it, but I don't recognize what it is specifically. Just curious

Comment: Not a templating language, but to solve the problem of allowing users a high degree of flexibility with date formatting, I drew inspiration from Phalcon Volt which I believe is heavily inspired by twig

Comment: @Don'tPanic - thats an interesting comment, as a long time project of mine is to create a template languages (i've written 3, but no like this).  The idea is to use a lexer to parse the template then turn it into an actual PHP class.  I'd be willing to discuss it more if your interested in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern like the following will capture the part between the parentheses:

```
\[[^\]]*\]\|\(([^\)]*)\)
```

The first part matches an open bracket followed by 0 or more non-closing brackets and finally a closing bracket:

```
\[[^\]]*\]
```

And the rest is similar.

Perhaps try it at https://regex101.com/.

Answer (score -1):

```
\[startDate\]\|\((.*)\).+
```

or without required "." on end:

```
\[startDate\]\|\((.*)\)
```